# Pass a context from one flux/mono to another

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Interesting things happen inside the webflux package. However, my journey in the source didn't solve the following question.

Let's say I have the following mono (or flux):

```
Mono hello = Mono.empty()
            .subscriberContext(ctx -> ctx.put("message", "hello"));
```

I use similar construct within a webfilter to enrich the pipeline with tenant and user data. Then in a controller a construct like this is used:

```
Mono world = Mono.subscriberContext()
            .map(ctx -> (String)ctx.get("message"));
```

The context of the hello mono is filled in the world mono. I tried to figure out how this is done, also for unit testing purposes.

In the end it remains a riddle. I tried to do this with the regular methods available on both mono/flux objects but I don't succeed in making the hello context available to the world mono. How can you fuse fluxes and monos and passing the context along the way to the upstream operators?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WebFlux takes your `world` Mono and builds a reactive chain on top of it, with an HTTP request within reactor-netty as the ultimate source. The `WebFilter` are part of the chain construction, so they can enrich the `Context` of the whole chain.

IIRC `Mono.subscriberContext()` will be used within a `flatMap`, which makes the main sequence `Context` available to its inners, so it can see the `Context` of `hello`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And although your answer is completely logic, it puzzled me still how it was done 'in concreto' in the webflux platform, just to make an abstraction of the process in my head and get more understanding of the reactor framework. This let me to this, which is an oversimplification, but does the same thing: https://gist.github.com/giespaepen/7240b0ec90de48aa45ee4c1ea185a0f3

Answer (score 7):

You want to do a couple of things:

1.) Publish a subscriber context

```
mono.subscriberContext({ Context context ->
    context.put("key", "value")
})
```

2.) Subscribe/access a subscriber context

```
mono.flatMap({ def r ->
    return Mono.subscriberContext().map({ Context context ->
        context.get("key")
        context.get("keyOrMapOrStateObject").put("someKey", "someData")
        return r
    })
})
```

3.) Potentially pass data from one event to a downstream event

```
mono.flatMap({ def r ->
    return Mono.subscriberContext().map({ Context context ->
        def someData = context.get("keyOrMapOrStateObject").get("someKey")
        return r
    })
})
```

All together it'll look something like: (this is groovy syntax)

```
mono.flatMap({ def r ->
    return Mono.subscriberContext().map({ Context context ->
        context.get("key")
        context.get("keyOrMapOrStateObject").put("someKey", "someData")
        return r
    })
}).flatMap({ def r ->
    return Mono.subscriberContext().map({ Context context ->
        def someData = context.get("keyOrMapOrStateObject").get("someKey")
        return r
    })
}).subscriberContext({ Context context ->
    context.put("key", "value")
    context.put("keyOrMapOrStateObject", new HashMap())
})
```

This is a rough outline - not ready 'as is' but it should help you understand the pattern.

Good luck!